# User Prompt Values input from Excel

Tags: business-intelligence, business-objects

This problem is related to User Prompt Values in SAP BO 4.1 Client Tool.

Generally we will select user prompt values from the list of values which we can obtain from Universe & the values were fetched from the database. Since List of Values are bulks (few hundred thousand values). Searching from that list one by one and giving it as an input is highly difficult. So if the user wants some 3000 values alone to be selected in that prompt, if they are mentioning that 3000 values in the Excel. By using that Excel how we can give it as an input selection.

Do you have any other alternative solution for this prompt selection problem?

Comment: Is this IN Excel or SAP?  Because I have the exact answer if it's Excel.

Comment: This is related to SAP BO 4.1 user prompt input .

Comment: are these predefined sets of values or random selections depending on whatever the user requires?

Comment: Hi Kristof ,   Predefined Values in list but bulk values so user requires the values to be typed in some excel/word from that they want to copy paste in prompt to see reports based on selected values .